# Headless driver on Windows/JRuby?

Tags: jruby, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver on Windows/JRuby.  My development has been with firefox.

Watir::Browser.new :firefox

For deployment I need a headless browser, JavaScript support is needed.  What options do I have for a headless browser?

Comment: I followed the example in this blog:
http://watirmelon.com/2010/12/14/watir-webdriver-a-detailed-introduction/
# This is working on Windows/JRuby!
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

require "watir-webdriver"
require 'selenium/server'

server = Selenium::Server.new("selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar", :background => true)
server.start
include Selenium
capabilities = WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.htmlunit(:javascript_enabled => true)
b = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
# Browser fun here
b.close
server.stop

Comment: So are you saying you got it working using the watirmelon stuff I pointed you to?  if so then perhaps accept the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure of your requirements for deployment with a headless browser, but my team is using [`phantomjs`](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) along with the [`jasminerice`](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) gem to automate our JavaScript testing on a headless browser with [`WebKit`](http://www.webkit.org/).

We are using JRuby 1.6.7 and Rails 3.2.3. In our project we are using CoffeeScript, and we wanted to leverage the Rails asset pipeline to do the compiling of CoffeeScript to JavaScript, which is what `jasminerice` does. If my understanding is correct, this will work for tests and code written in plain ol' JavaScript as well.

The set-up is a bit involved, and you might find wildly varying and probably out-dated accounts of other people getting this to work, but here is a [quick guide](https://gist.github.com/2474873) (gist on Github) that is working for me right now:

1. Add `jasminerice` to your `Gemfile` (gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/2474873#file_gemfile))
2. Get the latest static build for `phantomjs` on Windows at http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/list
3. Drop that `phantomjs.exe` executable somewhere on your `PATH`. We have this in our Rails project's `bin` folder, and we have updated our `PATH` to include that folder.
4. Create a `spec/javascripts` folder in your project directory, and create the following `spec.js` file that will pull into scope any required libraries or folders (gist [here](https://gist.github.com/2474873#file_spec.js))
5. Create a `spec/javascripts/support` folder in your project directory, and create the following `phantomjs-runner` file that will be used to invoke `phantomjs` to execute your JavaScript test files under `spec/javascripts`. (gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/2474873#file_phantom_runner))
6. Kick up your development Rails server and see `jasminerice` run your tests by going to http://localhost:5555/jasmine
7. Alternately, you can create a Rake task that will execute everything for you and return the results to the command line (gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/2474873#file_js.rake)).

And those are the hoops we had to jump through in order to get `jasminerice` and `phantomjs` to compile and run our CoffeeScript tests headless on Win/JRuby. Hope that helps!

Comment: How do I turn off the logging information for phantom js, i.e INFO, WARNING etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your stuff on a headless linux server, then see [this page](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) on the watir-webdriver blog

With Watir-Webdriver you get the same headless options that Webdriver has (since we use webdriver to drive the browser).  This has has been written up a few places such as these articles on [Alister's WatirMelon blog](http://watirmelon.com/tag/headless/).  Otherwise just do a google search for `watir-webdriver headless` and you will see a number of useful results.. I would however stick to stuff from the last year or so, earlier things may be a bit out of date by now.

Comment: Isn't the headless gem specific to X-Windows? I had success following the recipe at [Watir-webdriver a detailed introduction](http://watirmelon.com/2010/12/14/watir-webdriver-a-detailed-introduction/)

Comment: Good question Craig..  I've not used it myself, so unless it's described in the readme for the gem... lets see, headless wraps Xvfb which is a virtual frame buffer for ah yes Xwindows..  so you are likely correct in that.